# Given $f_Y(y;\lambda) = \lambda e^{-\lambda y}$ , $y > 0 $, show $\hat \lambda = Y_1$ is not consistent for $\lambda$

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose $Y_1, Y_2,\ldots,Y_n$ is a random sample from the exponential pdf, $f_Y(y;\lambda) = \lambda e^{-\lambda y}$ , $y > 0 $.

Show that $\hat \lambda = Y_1$ is not consistent for $\lambda$.

This is the solution: $P(Y_1 > 2\lambda) = \int_{2\lambda}^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda y} dy = e^{-2\lambda^2}$

$$P(|Y_1 - \lambda| < \lambda /2) < 1 - e^{-2\lambda^2} < 1$$

Thus, it is not consistent since it is less than $1$.

Can someone please explain where does that $2\lambda$ come from inside the paranthesis, And why the choice of $\lambda/2$ after the absolute value?

I don't understand this solution.

Thank you in advance.